# How can I push in this situation? (U+0096)

Tags: git, github

I want to push, so I wrote this code

```
git push origin
```

[[image: git push origin]]

Git said that I don't have correct access rights and there's no repository.

First, I don't know how to check my access rights, so I checked the existence of the repository

```
git remote -v
```

[image: git remote -v]

With my eyes, I think I have a repository... So I wrote this code additionally

```
git config --list
```

[image: git config --list]

...What is `<U+0096>`?

In this situation, how can I push my repository to GitHub?

Comment: This <U+0096> is a special character which you might have brought into your config with copy/pasting commands. Try to remove them.

Answer (score 2):

`<U+0096>` is an unprintable character ([start of guarded area](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0096)) which you probably got unintentionally by copy-pasting from your browser. It seems that `git remove` isn't printing it either.

To fix this, I'd forecibally reset `origin`'s URL to the correct URL without that character:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/hunnypooh/my-repo.git
```

With the corrected URL, `git push` should succeed.